# Is there a way to retrieve a SharePoint list to update a SQL database all with Java code?

Tags: java, sharepoint

I am setting up a SQL Server to store all the data from a SharePoint list to then create a file from the SQL Server data that is unimportant to this question.  Basically I need to extract the SharePoint data and put said data into a SQL Server.  I have a SQL Database that mimics the layout of the SharePoint site and now I just need to have a code that is able to retrieve this data and either place it directly into the SQL Server or retrieve this data into a .csv file as I have written code that places a .csv file into the SQL Server already.

I have tried using a Powershell script to generate a .csv file and then I ran a java code to put the .csv file into the SQL Server and that worked great until it was reported to me that the Powershell script was changing SharePoint data (Ex: a column named checked: yes/no would be marked no and I would run the script to retrieve the SharePoint data.  Someone would then try to update the checked column to yes (after it was checked) and the column would not update).  I could not find a reason this was happening as the script would only read data but apparently not.  This is a big problem as the SharePoint data is live data that is checked and updated daily by all employees

Java would be best as to only have someone run one program (update.java) and have the SQL Server be updated with new SharePoint data but any help is appreciated.  Sorry if this isn't specific enough or if it is a duplicate as it is my first question and I could not find another question that answered my question and I'm trying my best to be as specific as possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint REST service to extract list items from a SharePoint list.  Once you have the items, you can store them in SQL tables or save them to a data file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service